# What happens when I kill a command with ctrl+c?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface

Specifically, I ran a `rm -R /my/dir` by mistake on a ubuntu 10.04 machine.

When I realized the horror, within a few seconds, I quickly killed it with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command. It now seems I haven't lost any data. Is this possible? What did really happen in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> send `SIGINT` signal to the process.

Its default action is "Abnormal termination of the process" so basically pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> You are interrupting running process

If you were fast enough (before process scanned you directory structure) `rm` shouldn't delete anything (or maybe not if there wasn't much files in it).

Answer (score 1):

If `/my/dir` contains lots of directories and files, the initial scan might take a while and it's quite possible you managed to stop your command while it was still just reading the directory structure. Other than that, Ctrl+C does not provide you any undo capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky if you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> fast enough to not lose any file. How did you determine you did not lose any file?

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will interrupt the delete process and terminate it. So, you need to double-check your files/folders and restore any deleted files.

Comment: It was /var/www/ so lots of files and folders, and websites. Any file missing would break at least one of them and trigger a notice. I really was lucky. And stupid!

Comment: I agree with Khaled. You probably lost files but haven't noticed yet.

Answer (score 0):

You were lucky. The process has received an `SIGINT`, which (usually) kills the process. If you have not lost any data it is because the `rm` command was still busy traversing the directory structure, because it has to start deleting files in leaf directories without further subdirectories.